# Interactive plot selection in Altair does not hi-light points

Tags: python, interactive, vega-lite, altair

I am trying to generate 2 plots in Altair that share the same `selection`.

I would like to plot scatter and bar charts of population (y) vs Age (x). I am using the Altair built-in dataset `population`. The population is the sum of the `people` column in this dataset. The dataset has columns for `year`, `people`, `age` and `sex`. I can get total populate using `sum(people)` and plot this as `y` against `age`. For the bar chart, I can plot similarly `sum(people)` versus age and color using the `sex` column.

I am trying to set up a brush/selection between these 2 plots so that I can hilight in the scatter plot and simultaneously the bar plot is updated to reflect that selection. However, I am stuck with the following problem

I am using the [layered bar graph example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/layered_bar_chart.html#layered-bar-chart) from the Altair documentation for the example.

Here is the code

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum, if_
from vega_datasets import data
interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x', 'y'])

df = data.population.url

scatter = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('age:O', axis=alt.Axis(title='')),
    y='sum(people)',
    color=alt.condition(interval, 'sex:N', alt.value('lightgrey'))
).transform_filter(
    filter = datum.year == 2000
).transform_calculate(
    "sex", if_(datum.sex == 2, 'Female', 'Male')
).properties(
    selection=interval
)

bar = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(opacity=0.7).encode(
    alt.X('age:O', scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=17)),
    alt.Y('sum(people)', stack=None),
    color=alt.condition(interval, 'sex:N', alt.value('lightgrey')),
).transform_filter(
    filter = datum.year == 2000
).transform_calculate(
    "sex", if_(datum.sex == 2, 'Female', 'Male')
).properties(height=100, width=400)

scatter & bar
```

I have modified the code in the documentation example. I am first creating a scatter plot and then using the color based on the `selection`. Then I define a bar plot of the same 2 columns and again use the `selection` to specify the color. Here is the output

[image]

Now, I would like to drag a box across the top (scatter) plot to select some points and simultaneously the bottom (bar) chart should update based on the `selection`. When I drag in the top plot to make my `selection`, this happens

[image]

**Problems**

1. After dragging to make a selection in the top plot, the colors (inside and outside the selection) in both plots are changed to `lightgrey`. I expected, in both plots, inside the selection/brush to be hilighted but outside should be `lightgrey`.

How can I get a selection that is hilighted in both the top and bottom plots simultaneously?

**EDIT**

I want [this behaviour](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_linked_brush.html#faceted-scatter-plot-with-linked-brushing), where a brush/selection in one plot is simultaneously hilighted in a 2nd (linked) plot.

Package versions:

```
Python = 3.6
Altair = 2.2
Jupyter = 5.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a selection on an aggregated value, the best approach is to use an aggregate transform to define that quantity so that it is available to the entire chart.

Here is an example:

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum, if_
from vega_datasets import data

interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x', 'y'])


base = alt.Chart(data.population.url).transform_filter(
    filter = datum.year == 2000
).transform_calculate(
    "sex", if_(datum.sex == 2, 'Female', 'Male')
).transform_aggregate(
    population="sum(people)",
    groupby=['age', 'sex']
)

scatter = base.mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('age:O', title=''),
    y='population:Q',
    color=alt.condition(interval, 'sex:N', alt.value('lightgrey'))
).properties(
    selection=interval
)

bar = base.mark_bar(opacity=0.7).encode(
    alt.X('age:O', scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=17)),
    alt.Y('population:Q'),
    color=alt.condition(interval, 'sex:N', alt.value('lightgrey')),
).properties(height=100, width=400)

scatter & bar
```

Note that I took away the filtering by the interval selection on the lower plot, because that's not the behavior you described.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a very clear approach. `transform_aggregate()` looks very useful. You got me thinking of an analogous example from the documentation that I can adapt and use here (I think). I'll post it below.

Comment: Agreed about triggering a filter on the bottom interval - I'll remove it from the question....it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on (and adapting) the answer by @jakevdp above, I tried something similar to [this example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_with_histogram.html#scatter-plot-and-histogram-with-interval-selection) from the Interactive Charts section of the docs gallery.

Instead of using a `base` object, I used the `vconcat` function, which joins the `Chart` instances and passes the transform and data to the `vconcat` object. Here is the approach

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum, if_
from vega_datasets import data
interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x', 'y'])

scatter = alt.Chart().mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('age:O', title=''),
    y='population:Q',
    color=alt.condition(interval, 'sex:N', alt.value('lightgrey'))
).properties(
    selection=interval
)

bar = alt.Chart().mark_bar(opacity=0.7).encode(
    alt.X('age:O', scale=alt.Scale(rangeStep=17)),
    alt.Y('population:Q'),
    color=alt.condition(interval, 'sex:N', alt.value('lightgrey')),
).properties(height=100, width=400)

alt.vconcat(scatter, bar,
    data=data.population.url
).transform_filter(
    filter = datum.year == 2000
).transform_calculate(
    "sex", if_(datum.sex == 2, 'Female', 'Male')
).transform_aggregate(
    population="sum(people)",
    groupby=['age', 'sex']
)
```

This approach appears to give the same functionality as @jakevdp's answer.i.e. a selection can be made to the scatter (top) plot and this will be reflected in the bar chart (bottom), as required.